# How to pass a variable into the 'az pipelines variable-group variable create' command

Tags: devops, azure-cli, az

I am trying to use the "az pipelines variable-group variable create ..." command to create a variable which references a different variable. e.g.

```
az pipelines variable-group variable create --project MyTestProject -- 
group-id 15 --name ‘ApplicationName’ --value 'TestApp-$(env)'
```

where the variable “env” is defined in a variable-group within the same project library.

When I run the command above it gives the error:

```
“Failed to load python executable” “exit /b 1”.
```

Despite an error being generated the variable is created; in the example above the variable 'ApplicationName' has the value 'TestApp-$(env', the trailing bracket  character, ")", is missing and seems to be causing the problem.

The dollar sign, "$", and/or the opening bracket character "(" don't generate any error when used without the closing bracket ")".

I have tried escaping the closing bracket character with backslashes "\" and caret "`" characters but couldn't find any combination that would create the desired variable value, "TestApp-$(env)".

Could someone tell me how to escape the closing bracket so the variable is correctly created within the variable group.

I am running the following versions of az:

```
azure-cli                         2.0.73
command-modules-nspkg               2.0.3
core                              2.0.73
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.3
Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.12.0

Python (Windows) 3.6.6
```

Many Thanks,

Gary

Answer (score 4):

I have finally managed to figure out how to escape a variable whose name itself contains a different variable name. By calling the az cli command and wrapping the variable value  in double quotes and a single quote, the variable is correctly created in DevOps:

```
pipelines variable-group variable create --project MyTestProject -- group-id 15 --name ApplicationName' --value '"TestApp-$(env)"'
```

[DevOps-LibraryVariable-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfZ8B.png)

Comment: This works if you are passing the value directly in that command, doesn't work if the the value is in a variable and you are passing the variable. But good find, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a further expansion on this topic I had a need to pass the value as a variable. My source was in a key value pair. In this case I used the following.

```
$key = $var.Key
$value = '"{0}"' -f $var.Value
    
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id $groupId --org $org --project $project `
--name $key --value $value
```

Comment: Yes, yes, 1000 times yes for this answer.  And if you have multiple values, I needed to put those values in double quotes to get it properly picked up as an array of string values.  This was extremely helpful correctly putting the values for an Azure Vault secret reference from an app setting: $value = '"{0}=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName={1};SecretName={0})"' -f "$field", "$vault"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS and tools.

For example, in Windows OS, you can get environment variable with %variable_name%. So, the following would be right:

```
az pipelines variable-group variable create --project keyvault --group-id 1 --name "ApplicationName" --value "TestApp-%java_home%"
```

[image]

However, in PowerShell, you can get environment with "$env:variable_name". So, the following would be right:

```
az pipelines variable-group variable create --project keyvault --group-id 1 --name "ApplicationName2" --value "TestApp-$($env:java_home)"
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

So, in Azure Pipeline, you can use group variables as following:

```
pool: 
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands:
  -  msbuild
  -  visualstudio
  -  vstest

variables:
  - group: vargroup

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'CSP Azure (e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68)'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      echo the variable var1:%var1%
```

I have a variable group:

[image]

And you can see that: `echo the variable var1:%var1%` will be `echo the variable var1:value1`

[image]

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your response. 

My problem isn't that resolving a variable value and having it stored in a variable group, my problem is that the value I want to have in my variable group should actually contain a variable within the value. 

So using your example, instead of "value": "TestApp-C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_192" I want "value": "TestApp-$(java_home)". Where the variable   $(java_home) is defined within a variable group and not taken for an OS environment. 

Apologies if my description was misleading; thanks again for taking the time to try and answer the question

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks again for the reply. 
My problem isn’t evaluating an environment variable at runtime, but rather defining a variable whose name contains a variable within the name. I have finally managed to figure out a solution to my problem, in the end it was simple. I’ll document my solution below. 
Cheers, Gary